# IOS Swift assetForURL error

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, alassetslibrary

i just want to get an image asset from the ALAsset in ios 8 with Swift.

i use the SNImagePicker for multiple images picking.

With objective-c i use this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary assetForURL:info[i] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset aspectRatioThumbnail]];
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {     }];
```

With swift, i have try to do this:

```
func imagePicker(imagePicker: SNImagePickerNC!, didFinishPickingWithMediaInfo info: NSMutableArray!){
    var i: Int = Int(0);
    for (i; i < info.count as Int; i++){
        var url: NSURL = info[i] as NSURL
        var assetLibrary: ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()

        //
        //assetLibrary.assetForURL(NSURL?(), resultBlock: ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock?(), failureBlock: ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock?())            
        //

        assetLibrary.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: {
            (asset: ALAsset!) in
            if asset != nil {
                var assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
                var iref = assetRep.fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue()
                var image =  UIImage(CGImage: iref)

                self.imageViewPreview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
                self.imageViewPreview.image = image

            }
            }, failureBlock: {
                (error: NSError!) in

                NSLog("Error!", nil)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

With this snippet, i obtain an error:

> Type 'CVarArg' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing NSLog("Error!", nil) with NSLog("Error!"). This statement is causing Swift to throw unexpected error messages.

[image]

[image]